# Como consultar datos de tablas padres mediante las claves foraneas. oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una tabla de Personal con la siguiente estuctura:

```
create table PERSONAL
(
  personal_id NUMBER(8) not null,
  nombre      VARCHAR2(50),
  apellido    VARCHAR2(50),
)
alter table PERSONAL
  add constraint PK_ID primary key (PERSONAL_ID);
```

Y una tabla de lugares de la siguiente forma:

```
create table LUGAR
(
  lugar_id    NUMBER(8) not null,
  desc_lugar  VARCHAR2(50),
  latitud     VARCHAR2(50),
  longitud    VARCHAR2(50)
)
alter table LUGAR
  add constraint LU_ID primary key (LUGAR_ID);
```

Además tengo una tabla que relaciona el personal con los lugares:

```
create table LUGAR_PERSONA
(
  lugar_id    NUMBER(8) not null,
  personal_id NUMBER(8) not null
);
alter table LUGAR_PERSONA
  add constraint FK_lugar FOREIGN KEY (lugar_id) REFERENCES lugar(lugar_id)
  add constraint FK_personal FOREIGN KEY (personal_id) REFERENCES personal(personal_id);
```

Bueno la pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para que al realizar una consulta a la tabla de Lugar por persona me traiga los datos relacionados de los personales y de los lugares del id correspondiente?

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer una join relacionando las tablas por los campos en común:

```
select 
    p.nombre, l.nombre 
from 
    personal p, lugar l, lugar_persona lp
where 
    l.lugar_id=lp.lugar_id
and 
    p.personal_id=lp.personal_id
```

Comment: Me solucionaste el dia, en 3 minutos stack overflow me dejara marcarte como respuesta válida y lo haré. saludos